# Converting date from Local time zone to UTC and then to local

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, ionic-framework

I am making an application in AngularJs.
But the problem is that the database is controlled by someone else.
They are saving time in database as ISD(Indian standard).
When i am calling webservices to get those dates its coming in form of string like this YYYY/MM/DD HH/MM/SS example 2015/02/23 23/59/01.
I am having a list of dates which i have to show using ng-repeat like this.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in MeIdeaList | orderBy:'-CreatedDate'" style="background-color:rgb(25, 26, 0);" ng-click="ShowIdeaDetails(item.Id)">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col col-80" style="color:white">
                   <p> {{item.Title}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-20" style="color:red">
                    <b>{{item.Status}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col col-70" style="color:white">
                    {{item.CreatedDate}}
                </div>
                <div class="col col-30">
                    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory" style="float:right;color:white"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ion-item>
```

Now i want this Date to be shown as Local time from where the user is accessing the data.
Like if i am in U.S. the date will come from database as ISD only.How to convert this ISD into UTC and then get the timezone and add or minus the minutes and show that to user in UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js also to convert date from local time to utc and vice versa.

```
moment('07-18-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY').utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")

moment.utc('2014-02-19 05:24:32 AM').toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setDateLocal(input)
{
  var date = input.split(" "); //remember input needs to be as you described.
  date = date[0] + "T" + date[1].replace(/\//g, ":") + "+0000";
  var ist = 19800000; //time zone is IST, which is 5.30 from UTC in milliseconds
  var utcDate = new Date(Date.parse(date)-ist).toUTCString();
  return new Date(Date.parse(utcDate));

}

document.body.innerHTML += setDateLocal("2015/02/23 23/59/01");
```

This function will take the input from the database. Convert it to timestamp and subtract 5.30 hours from it (which is the difference between UTC and IST). Last step is convert it to local.

Comment: Date.parse(date) is   resulting in NaN.

Comment: Is the input in this format? `2015/02/23 23/59/01`. The format you described.

Comment: yes...date = date[0] + "T" + date[1].replace(/\//g, ":") + "+0000";this line is working fine.4th line is giving error.

Comment: Because my browser shows: `Sat Feb 21 2015 17:59:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd)) `

Comment: Man..its now working...in code snippet also..its giving error.

Comment: There was a minor bug in it, fixed it, however if you supply a date in the format you described it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = input.split(" "); 
                date = date[0] + "T" + date[1].replace(/\//g, ":") + "+00"+":"+"00";
                date=date.replace("/","-");
                date=date.replace("/","-");
                alert(date);
                var ist = 19800000; //time zone is IST, which is 5.30 from UTC in milliseconds
                var utcDate = new Date(Date.parse(date)-ist).toUTCString();
                 alert(utcDate);
```

Maintaining "-" between dates and ":" between time is important.